# asp.net 4.0 has not been registered VS 2010 after VS2015 install

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Getting this error when opening a VS 2010 project after install of VS 2015 RTM:

> Asp.Net has not been registered on the webserver you need to manually configure your webserver for Asp.net 4.0.

`aspnet_regiis -i` does NOT help. The project still runs and debugs fine, so really just a nuisance, but anyone know of a fix?

Other than that, VS2010, VS2013 and VS2015 seem to coexists pretty well so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our developers have the same problem with VS2010 after vs2015 installed and found a solution that worked when aspnet_regiis does not.

Microsoft offers an update to address this problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002340

Comment: this error "Asp.Net has not been registered on the webserver you need to manually configure your webserver for Asp.net 4.0." can only be fixed this way...   thanks!